# Использование статичного метода в классе, который возвращает List<> с типом самого класса

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне необходимо заполнить DataGrid данными из БД. Для этого использую

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = Group.GetGroups();
```

Правильно ли использовать статичный метод класса, который возвращает список с типом самого класса? Будет ли очищаться память, если для заполнения грида несколько раз вызвать Group.GetGroups()?

```
public class Group
    {
        public int IdGrp { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }

        public static List<Group> GetGroups()
        {
            List<Group> Groups = new List<Group>();

            try
            {
                using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionPROD))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select a.idgrp, a.name from groups a", connection))
                    {
                        OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Groups.Add(new Group()
                            {
                                IdGrp = Int32.Parse(reader["idgrp"].ToString()),
                                GroupName = reader["name"].ToString()//,
                            });
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                
            }

            return Groups;
        }
    }
```

Спасибо за советы!

Comment: А теперь попробуйте покрыть тестами свой проект. Именно те места, где используется этот метод.

Comment: я не силен в тестах, но создал тестовый метод    [TestMethod]
        public void GetGroupsTest()
        {
            var groups = Group.GetGroups();
        }. Все ок!

Comment: Нет, протестируйте не этот метод, а другие методы, в которых вызывается этот. Юнит-тест должен быть быстрым как молния. То есть вместо реального получения данных из БД (которой может вовсе не быть на билд-сервере), следует использовать мок (фейковые данные). А это становится невозможно при использовании статического метода.

Answer (score 1):

Память будет "очищаться", когда на возвращенный список не останется активных ссылок.

Правильно ли иметь в объекте данных метод, который читает такие объекты из базы данных, - вопрос мнений.